# C Binary operation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to solve a C operation in one step without using a loop.

I have:

```
unsigned int8 Dummy = 0x3F;//This values are for reference only, so can be different
unsigned int8 Dummy_2 = 0x02;

Dummy = Dummy ^ Dummy_2;
```

Now Dummy = 0x3D

I must to set the Dummy bits to 0 the bits that are 1 in Dummy_2.
My code works ok the first time but if I perform the code two times it toggles back to 1.
I can do this with a loop but for the clarity of the code I'm trying to do it in one line.

Comment: Hint: look at what `~Dummy_2` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd negate(*) `Dummy_2` and then use that as a mask:

```
Dummy &= (~Dummy_2);
```

(*) EDIT:
As the busybee pointed out in the comments, "negate" is an arithmetic term. The proper term here would be "to complement `Dummy_2`.

Comment: "Negate" is more an arithmetic operation, I would call it "invert" or "complement".

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks. I had this nagging thought that "negate" was a wrong term, but could find a better one. I've edited my answer with your suggestion.